# Difference between a MATLAB code and the .m program script

Tags: matlab

I am completing a task on MATLAB which requires me to submit both my 'MATLAB code' and 'a copy of the .m program script used (e.g. to plot figures, perform analysis, etc)'

I have spent hours fiddling with MATLAB for the first time- and I actually really enjoy it, but I don't understand what the 'MATLAB code' and '.m program script' are. Could it have something to do with what is in the command window vs the editor window? I have tried to find an answer to this already, but I have only been able to find information about script vs function, and not code and script. And I didn't really understand what I read. Does someone have an explanation for these that doesn't use too much programming jargon, or if it does, explains what the technical words mean?

Comment: I would consider "MATLAB code" and "an .m file" as the same thing. Whether the .m file contains a function or a script, it's all still MATLAB code.

Comment: Why don't you **ask** the person who gave you the task? They may mean they want all the .m files that make up any functions, etc, you have written + a main .m script which ties it all together (runs your functions, plots your results, etc). If it was not made clear in whatever class you're taking what you need to do, ask for clarification. We can only make educated guesses.